# Using Git bash for python installations and task

Tags: python, linux, windows, command-line, git-bash

I have been given a windows laptop at work to work on a web app using flask which involves a little bit of computer vision and nlp as well. I wanted to take this chance to transition to the command style in linux. Since it is my office laptop I am not allowed to dual boot or install anything unless it is specified. So I was wondering if gitbash can be used to transition to linux commands instead of the windows cmd or the anaconda prompt?
I did try using gitbash but other than commits it is a hassle when using pip or sudo. Many times it does not recognize the command even though i have the python scripts added in PATH but it still isnt working with sudo and python. I felt i will face similar issues ahead so wanted to know if it is a good idea at all to use gitbash to practice transitioning to linux or is there any other alternate which is more smooth and hassle less.

Comment: do you think it might be possible to install WSL or Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the best way to learn Linux when you only have Windows installed is to use either Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) or to use Linux-based Docker containers.

gitbash won't offer the full functionality of Linux, since it is largely relies on the binary commands and various components of Windows.

Docker has a number of other benefits.
For example if your Flask application is Dockerised, it would make it easier to deploy on the server when needed.